# How to map node objects to node Ids in d3 tutorial?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

I'm working through this tutorial -

http://flowingdata.com/2012/08/02/how-to-make-an-interactive-network-visualization/

There's a part I don't understand.

"Finally, we map node id's to node objects and then replace the source and target in our links with the node objects themselves, instead of the id's that were in the raw data. This allows D3's force layout to work correctly, and makes it possible to add/remove nodes without worrying about getting our nodes array and links array out of order."

```
setupData = (data) ->
  # initialize circle radius scale
  countExtent = d3.extent(data.nodes, (d) -> d.playcount)
  circleRadius = d3.scale.sqrt().range([3, 12]).domain(countExtent)
  data.nodes.forEach (n) ->
    # set initial x/y to values within the width/height
    # of the visualization
    n.x = randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*width)
    n.y = randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*height)
    # add radius to the node so we can use it later
    n.radius = circleRadius(n.playcount)
  # id's -> node objects
  nodesMap  = mapNodes(data.nodes)
  # switch links to point to node objects instead of id's
  data.links.forEach (l) ->
    l.source = nodesMap.get(l.source)
    l.target = nodesMap.get(l.target)
    # linkedByIndex is used for link sorting
    linkedByIndex["#{l.source.id},#{l.target.id}"] = 1

  data
```

That's said after the part about the function setupData(). I don't understand what it means to map node ids to node objects, because it seems the node objects are created afterwards by the update() method.

What are these node objects? How would mapNodes()

Answer (score 1):

When creating a force directed graph, you must supply the data for each node as well as how the nodes are connected. The information for how they are connected, is set by the [force.links([])](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-links) method called directly on a force graph. Each data point in the array of links has a source and a target, which are defined as either indexes (the position in the array of data), or as the actual objects in the array itself.

eg.

```
var banana = {type: "fruit", color: "yellow"};
var apple = {type: "fruit", color: "red"};
..etc

var data = [apple, banana, sausage, peach, bagel, kimchee.. etc etc ]

var links = [{source: 1,target: 2}, 
             {source: 2, target: 10}, ....etc. ] //as index
```

or

```
 var links = [{source:banana,target:apple},
              {source:apple, target:orange}, 
              ....etc. ] //as object
```

In the [initial data](http://projects.flowingdata.com/tut/interactive_network_demo/data/call_me_al.json), each song has an id, and the source/targets are just defined as pointing to those ids. With this step, he substitues the actual objects which match the ids for the initial id strings.